# ALTER PROCEDURE doesn't work within IF statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Why doesn't SQL Server T-SQL let you run an `ALTER PROCEDURE` statement within an `IF` statement for some object types? This can be solved by wrapping things with `Execute()` but I want to understand the reason that's necessary.

I'm running SQL Server 2019 CTP3.0.

Given this:

```
create proc delme 
as 
begin 
    select 1 from sysobjects 
end
go
```

This doesn't work:

```
if (1=1) begin
    alter procedure dbo.delme 
    as
    begin
        select top 1 * from sysobjects
    end
end
```

But this does work:

```
if (1=1) 
begin
    execute('alter procedure dbo.delme 
             as
             begin
                 select top 1 * from sysobjects
             end')
end
```

In testing other object types I didn't find consistency. With tables for instance, it works:

```
create table delme2(a int)
go

if (1=1) begin
    alter table delme2 add b int 
end
```

But for functions it doesn't work (like procedures):

```
create function delme3() returns int
begin
    return 1
end
go

if (1=1) begin
    alter function delme3() returns int
    begin
        return 1
    end
end
```

Comment: It's not consistent, but it is documented. You can't `CREATE` or `ALTER` procedures or functions except as their own batch, and the whole batch becomes part of the definition (`BEGIN` and `END` are actually optional, which has tripped up quite a few people who put statements after the `END` and are surprised when they become part of the procedure). There is no "reason" it's necessary other than that this is the way it's worked since a very long time ago and there's very little incentive for MS to change it (and potentially risk breaking other things).

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert - I guess I'll just have to accept the quirk. And I definitely understand why MS can't change, that would break a million scripts.